# я хочу сделать команду для бота "покажи правила" но discord.py не воспринимает команду из 2х или более слов,как мне это сделать?

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

[image: вот кусочек кода:]
я хочу сделать команду для бота "покажи правила" но discord.py не воспринимает команду из 2х или более слов,как мне это сделать?

вот кусочек кода:

Comment: Пожалуйста, не приводите код в виде скриншота, скопируйте его.

Comment: В Дискорде команды состоят только из одного слова. Все что после первого слова считается аргументами команды.

Answer (score 1):

В следующий раз прикрепляйте код в виде текста, а то на вряд ли кто-то поможет

---

В данном случае `discord` берет в качестве названия команды название функции `покажи_правила`, так что и вводить команду нужно с использованием нижнего подчеркивания.

Название команды можно указать через параметр `aliases` в декораторе `@bot.command()`, но указав там название из двух слов с пробелом, команда автоматически примет в виде названия только первое слово, то есть будет называться `!покажи`

---

Данная проблема решается вот таким костылем, где команда `!покажи` принимает в качестве первого аргумента второе слово. В данном случае - `правила`

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['покажи'])
async def _rules(ctx, arg):
    if arg == 'правила':
        await ctx.send('Вызвана команда "!покажи правила"')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]